# Update Item in DynamoDB (Add new item to the end)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, addition

I want to update my DynamoDB table with a lambda function.
In my table I have a user and I want to save objects in an array (results_list). I am able to update my results_list with the updateItem ADD. But I don`t know if/how I can save the new object at the end of the existing array.

Can someone tell me, if I can push the new object to the existing array to the end? I know that it is possible by using list_append with the set function (but the set function creates always two objects in the database)

```
UpdateExpression: "ADD #result_list :result"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `list_append` function. You will need to provide the item you are adding as a single object in a list.

`SET #result_list = list_append(#result_list, :values)`

where values is set to a list of the value you want to add.

See for a more complete example. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingListElements